# Can Nearby API scans Eddystone without registering beacon to Google api?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, google-nearby, eddystone

I have a board that broadcast beacons as Eddystone formate.
I want to use nearby api to scan that on my Android mobile.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunstely, no.  Google does not provide any way to locally register beacons to be detected.  In order to use Nearby to get callbacks of discovered Eddystone beacons, you must register those beacons in the Google cloud servers.

Detection without cloud registration is possible with other SDKs like the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library).